# Problem with Accesing array data Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to access data of var a so it is: 245   but instead it only accesses the last one. so if i print it out it says 5

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var B = A[[1], [3], [4]];

console.log(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

When accessing an object using square bracket notation — `object[expression]` — the expression resolves to the string name of the property.

The expression `[1], [3], [4]` consists of three array literals separated by comma operators. So it becomes `[4]`. Then it gets converted to a string: `"4"`. Hence your result.

JavaScript doesn't have any syntax for picking non-contiguous members of an array in a single operation. (For contiguous members you have the [slice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).)

You need to get the values one by one.

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var B = [A[1], A[3], A[4]];

console.log(B.join(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var B = [A[1], A[3], A[4]];

console.log(B)
```

Comment: i tried this but i didn't put bracket notation before the first one so it was A[[1], A[3], [4]] I shouldve thought about that

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access A multiple times for each index.

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var B = A[1];

console.log(A[1], A[3], A[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access them directly like that.
If you want to access index 2 for example, you should do `console.log(A[1]);`
You can't access multiple indices at the same time.
A variable can have only one value.

Answer (score 0):

@Quentin solution resolve the problem, I wrote this solution to recommend you to create an array of index, and iterate over it.

Note: You are getting the last index, because you are using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). The comma operator allows you to put multiple expressions. The resulting will be the value of the last comma separated expression.

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const indexes = [1,3,4];
const B = indexes.map(i => A[i]).join``;
console.log(B);
```